# Node js: Why do I get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined``` when I call an async function from an express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm calling a async function from an express route when certain conditions are met. However when the recursive function is called the I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`. Why are the .json() methods undefined in the recursive function when called outside of a route? Is there away of remedying this?

Express route calls the recursive function

asyncHandler function

```
const asyncHandler = (callback) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}
```

```
router.patch( "/user/match/:id", authenticateUser, asyncHandler(async (req, res, next, error) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req);

  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const errorMessages = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg);
    return res.status(400).json({ error: errorMessages });
  }

  const updateObject = req.body.likes;
  console.log(updateObject)

  const likedUser = await User.findOne({ _id: updateObject });


  if (req.body.likes) {

    await User.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: req.params.id }, { $push: { likes: updateObject._id } });

//function being called.

    recursive(likedUser, user)

  } else if (req.body.dislikes) {

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $push: { dislikes: req.body.dislikes._id } },

      function (error, doc) {
        if (error) {
          return res.json({ success: false, message: err.message });
        }

        res.json({ message: "Nope" });

        return res.status(204).end();

      }
    );
  }

})
);
```

Recursive function

```
const recursive = async (match, user, req, res, error, next) => {

  console.log(match.likes)

  const newUser = {
    _id: user._id,
    firstName: user.firstName,
    path: user.path
  };

  console.log(newUser, "new user")

  const newMatch = {
    _id: match._id,
    firstName: match.firstName,
    path: match.path
  };

  console.log(newMatch, "new match")

  try {

    for (let i = 0; i < match.likes.length; i ++) {

      console.log(match.likes[i], 'like._id');
      
      if ( user._id.equals(match.likes[i]) ) {

        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { $push: { matches: newMatch } });
    
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: match._id }, { $push: { matches: newUser } });

        const newConversation = new Conversation({ members: [user._id, match._id] });

        console.log(newConversation, "New conversation");
      
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          res.status(500).json(error);

        } else {
          const savedConversation = await newConversation.save();
          console.log(savedConversation);
          res.status(200).json(savedConversation, { message: 'Its a match!' }).end();
        }
      } else {
        console.log("match")
        res.json({ message: 'Liked' })
      }
    };
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.json(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `recursive` function takes 6 parameters: `match`, `user`, `req`, `res`, `error`, and `next`. However, your `recursive` call looks like this: `recursive(likedUser, user)`. You're only sending it 2 arguments. So, while the `match` and `user` parameters are being set, the other 4 are not assigned and are left as `null`.

Then, the code fails when it tries to use `res.json` in your recursive function, because `res` is set to `null` and obviously `null` has no methods named `json`. If you want to fix this, you need to actually pass your variables (req, res, etc.) into the recursive function call.